# How to get data object in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, service, flutter-provider

I have JSON data like this:

```
{
    "iduser": 3,
    "fname": "joni"
}
```

I want to display it on the home page.

Previously I have created a model class below:

usermodel.dart

```
class UserModel {
  int id;
  String fname;

  UserModel(
    this.id,
    this.fname,
  );

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> response) {
    id = response['iduser'];
    fname = response['fname'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'fname': fname,
    };
  }
}
```

and I created a service page to interact with API

```
class AuthService {
  String baseUrl = 'https://myurl.com';
  Future<UserModel> getUser() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var id = prefs.getInt('id');
    var token = prefs.getString('token');
    var url = '$baseUrl/users/$id';
    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };

    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: headers,
    );

    print(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(data);
      return user;
    } else {
      print(response.body);
      throw Exception('Failed');
    }
  }
}
```

home.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Text( ), //get json fname
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

before I run but I get error type:

> '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List>'

How to display the fname I get from the service on the home page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make home.dart a stateful widget and get the data in initstate and store in a variable. Use that variable to display the data here is how

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAsync();
  }

  UserModel user;
  getAsync() async {
    try {
      user = await AuthService().getUser();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    if (mounted) setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (user == null) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    else
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(user.fname), //get json fname
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: nice info I will try first

Comment: thank you for all who have answered, i will study again

Answer (score 1):

You have two options;

1. Use FutureBuilder
2. Convert to StatefullWidget

I give you FutureBuilder example;

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<UserModel>(
      future: AuthService().getUser(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting: return Text('Loading....');
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            } else {
              final data = snapshot.data;
              return Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(data.fname), //get json fname
                ),
              );
            }
        }

      },
    );
  }
}
```

Also, as far as I can see, there is a problem with the id conversion of the fromJson and toJson methods. Related fields should be 'iduser' according to json data.

```dart
class UserModel {
  int id;
  String fname;

  UserModel(
    this.id,
    this.fname,
  );

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> response) {
    id = response['iduser'];
    fname = response['fname'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'iduser': id,
      'fname': fname,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for all who have answered, i will study again

Answer (score 0):

First, you may want to be consistent in your map key to get the desired result.

You have to replace the key of flutter map version from:

`id = response['id']; => id = response['iduser'];`

*or vice versa.*

Now in your homepage, you need to instantiate the **AuthService** class in order to access the function that will get the specified user.

You need to use **FutureBuilder** in order to automatically update the **Text** if the data was fetched.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AuthService _authService = AuthService();
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: FutureBuilder<User>(
        future: _authService.getUser(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data.firstName);
          }
          /// Show some loading artifact while fetching the
          /// user data from the server.
          else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for all who have answered, i will study again